# C# - Custom encoding system to store array/lists

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization

So I've delved into serializing data using Binary Formatter, which I am impressed with. But the problem is compatibility. I want my serialized data to be portable, therefore accessible by different platforms. So XML serialization may seem like the answer, but the files produced are too large and there is no need for human-readability.

So I thought about creating my own encoding/serialization system so that I can write a `long[]` array and a `string[]/List<string>` containing Hexadecimal vales to a file.

I thought about converting all of the arrays to into byte[], but I'm not sure whether I should be concerned about character text encoding. I only intend on serializing/encoding arrays containing Hexadecimal and long values.

```
byte[] Bytes = HexArray.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

After converting all of the arrays to byte[], I could write them to a file, whilst noting of the byte offsets of the individual arrays so that they could be recovered.

Any ideas on a better way to do this? I really don't wanna resort to XML. Wish the BinaryFormatter was portable. This has to cross-platform so it can't be affected by endianness

Comment: Binary data is portable so I don't know what your concerns are.  Binary would be the most compact and quickest to send.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at Protocol Buffers (protobuf):

> a language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible way of serializing structured data for use in communications protocols, data storage, and more.

A couple of popular C# libraries are:

- [protobuf (Google)](https://github.com/google/protobuf) and
- [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)

Comment: Good answer. You might want to mention the more general subject: [Binary XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_XML).